# CSV file content, replace by using RegEx

Tags: csv, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml, lucee

I have a CSV file containing a line like this:

```
"Jakins, Ann-Margaret",Ms.,Ann-Margaret, ,Jakins,Ms. Ann-Margaret Jakins,""Callawera"Property""Callawera"Property""allawera",Thallon,4497,Australia,Queensland
```

Is there a way to remove the quote, in between the two quotes, for the field `"Callawera Property Callawera Property allawer"`? Is there Regex to select what is between the two quote values, so the result is this:

```
"Jakins, Ann-Margaret",Ms.,Ann-Margaret, ,Jakins,Ms. Ann-Margaret Jakins,"Callawera Property Callawera Property allawera",Thallon,4497,Australia,Queensland
```

Comment: Hi....  I would make an attempt first and post your code and then say what is not working!

Comment: I've use cfcsv tag and this tag only read the 10 records but csv file has the 100 recodes.

Comment: ,""Callawera"Property""Callawera"Property""allawera",

Comment: above content replace to  
,"Callawera"Property Callawera Property allawera",

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the entire file assembled, you will not be able to fix the quote in between the two quotes. There is no possible way for any regular expression (or even a human, for that matter) to consistently & reliably determine where the intended boundaries are for each of the fields in the CSV.

*While there may be tricks you can pull with RegEx that work for limited sets of data, there is nothing that is generally applicable for all possible data sets.*

Therefore, **you must do this while the file is being assembled.** On each and every field, replace any `"` (double quotes) with `""` (two double quotes) and make sure the entire field is surrounded with double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a somewhat non-standard format.  Excel can read files with double quotations and carriage returns, but often can't export it correctly.  ColdFusion is the same way... unless you use [opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), a CSV (comma-separated values) parser library for Java.

opencsv can be a little complex to integrate if you haven't used java. I wrote a demo script here:
https://gist.github.com/JamoCA/6062864

**NOTE:** If you use Windows, [CSVed](http://csved.sjfrancke.nl/) is a powerful CSV file editor that can manipulate any CSV file, separated with any separator.

```
<!---
Convert CSV file to a ColdFusion query object using opencsv.
    Requirements:
    - ColdFusion 8+  ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_ColdFusion )
    - opencsv - free parser library for Java ( http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/ ) 
        http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/     
        opencsv supports all the basic csv-type things you're likely to want to do:
        - Arbitrary numbers of values per line
        - Ignoring commas in quoted elements
        - Handling quoted entries with embedded carriage returns (ie entries that span multiple lines)
        - Configurable separator and quote characters (or use sensible defaults)
        - Read all the entries at once, or use an Iterator style model
        - Creating csv files from String[] (ie. automatic escaping of embedded quote chars)

NOTE: To use opencsv in ColdFusion:
    - copy "opencsv-2.3.jar" to "ColdFusion Class Path" (in CFAdmin > Server Settings > Java and JVM)
    - Specifying custom Java library path in the Application.cfc without dynamic loading
      http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-106e125d1353e804331-7ffe.html
    - Use JavaLoader http://javaloader.riaforge.org/
--->

<!--- Configure CSV file & delimiter --->
<cfset CSVFile = "c:\sampleCSVFile.csv">
<cfset Delimiter = ",">

<!--- Read file using opencsv --->
<cfscript>
fileReader = createobject("java","java.io.FileReader");
fileReader.init(CSVFile);
csvReader = createObject("java","au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader");
csvReader.init(fileReader, Delimiter);
ArrData = csvReader.readAll();
csvReader.close();
fileReader.close();
</cfscript>

<!--- Determine if any records exist --->
<cfif not arraylen(ArrData)>
     <p>No data in file.</p>
     <cfexit>
<cfelseif arraylen(ArrData) lt 1>
     <p>No records.</p>
     <cfexit>
</cfif>

<!--- Convert 2 dimensional array of rows & columns to a ColdFusion query --->
<cfscript>
GetResults = QueryNew(ArrayToList(ArrData[1]));
Rows = arraylen(ArrData);
Fields = arraylen(ArrData[1]);
for(thisRow=2; thisRow lte Rows; thisRow = thisRow + 1){
    queryaddrow(GetResults);
    for(thisField=1; thisField lte Fields; thisField = thisField + 1){
        QuerySetCell(GetResults, ArrData[1][thisfield], ArrData[thisRow][thisfield]);
    }
}
</cfscript>

<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="No">
<cfdump var="#GetResults#">
```